Display a Product ACF field value in WooCommerce PDF Invoice
I am trying to call an ACF value from a WooCommerce product, so I can display it in an invoice, but having issues on grabbing the specific information for that. I've added a screenshot of the 'Internal ID' which is the ACF field and value.
ACF Field Value in a product (setting example):

I need to add that to the following:
<?php do_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_before_order_details', $this->get_type(), $this->order ); ?>

<table class="order-details">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product"><?php _e( 'Product Name', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
            <th class="reference"><?php _e( 'Product Reference', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
            <th class="pick_quantity"><?php _e( 'Pick Qty', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
            <th class="price"><?php _e( 'Price ex.VAT', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
            <th class="vat"><?php _e( 'VAT', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
            <th class="price"><?php _e( 'Price inc.VAT', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $this->get_order_items() as $item_id => $item ) : ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'wpo_wcpdf_item_row_class', 'item-'.$item_id, $this->get_type(), $this->order, $item_id ); ?>">
                <td class="product">
                    <?php $description_label = __( 'Description', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); // registering alternate label translation ?>
                    <span class="item-name"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>
                    <?php do_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', $this->get_type(), $item, $this->order  ); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="reference">
                    
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $item['sku'] ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['sku']; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $item['thumbnail']?> 
                </td>
                <td class="pick_quantity"><?php 
        echo $item['quantity'];         
                    ?></td>
                <td class="price"><?php echo $item['line_total']; ?></td>
                <td class="vat"><?php echo $item['line_tax']; ?></td>
                <td class="price"><?php echo $item['order_price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

Ideally I would like to change out the line:
<?php if ( ! empty( $item['sku'] ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['sku']; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>

for the 'Internal ID' from ACF.
If anyone could help that would be great, as I'm a complete novice with this.

First in your ACF Field Groups settings for the "Internal ID" field Name (not the field Label), you need to get the correct slug used for it:

Simply replace your code line:
<?php if ( ! empty( $item['sku'] ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['sku']; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>

with the following:
<?php if ( $interval_id = get_field('interval-id', $item['product_id']) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><dd class="sku"><?php echo $interval_id; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>

replacing 'interval-id' with the correct slug used in your ACF Field Groups settings for the "Internal ID" field.
